# Could We Add a Customized Confirmation Screen for Question Posters below a Certain Reputation Threshold?

Tags: feature-request

Disclaimer: I am still new here, and haven't fully assimilated the PSE culture. Nor do I know how difficult it is (permission-wise or coding-wise) to make custom changes to one of the SE subsites.
However, I have already noticed a frequently-occurring problem at PSE where new posters post content contrary to site policy, including content that is copied from elsewhere, without proper attribution, and puzzles that are part of ongoing contests elsewhere. It seems to me that this ties up a lot of time of the mods and regular users, and also fills the recent thread list with [closed] content.
It seems to me that this could be at least somewhat resolved by implementing a setup whereby all users posting questions who have not yet achieved a certain reputation threshold are presented with a clear, forceful, consisely-written information box which **requires** them to click that they **certify** that what they are about to post meets certain criteria (not part of an ongoing competition, not copied from somewhere else, etc.). The exact wording and the exact threshold could be decided by the mods and regular users who wish to have a say.
I don't think that the current system is effectively weeding out enough of these posts.
What do you think?

Comment: [This seems relevant.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/278659). The ask page is network-wide, but it can be customised per-site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yeah, that looks perfect for the job. Thanks.